# $1 and \1 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

When using regular expressions in Ruby, what is the difference between $1 and \1?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

\1 is a backreference which will only work in the same `sub` or `gsub` method call, e.g.:

```
"foobar".sub(/foo(.*)/, '\1\1') # => "barbar"
```

$1 is a global variable which can be used in later code:

```
if "foobar" =~ /foo(.*)/ then 
  puts "The matching word was #{$1}"
end
```

Output:

```
"The matching word was bar"
# => nil
```

Comment: Note that [Ruby's treatment of single vs double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3028799/303896) can get in your way when trying to use backreferences.

Comment: didn't understand much, can someone please provide some more explanation

Comment: @YasirAzgar `.sub()` is a method call. `'\1'` can (apparently) only be used  within the scope of a `sub` or `gsub` method call. In the first example, `"foobar".sub(/foo(.*)/, '\1\1')`, `'\1'` is within the scope of the `sub` method. In the second example, `$1` is referenced outside of a `sub` / `gsub` method. The example shows it referenced shortly after a `=~` call, but that's irrelevant. Apparently, the use of a regex sets `$1`, which, as a global variable, can be referenced anywhere.

Comment: Also FYI, apparently `$1` is not a true global variable. In ruby, creating a variable that begins with `$` makes it a global variable (but apparently `$1` is special and is not actually a global variable). The intricacies of the `$1` variable are, apparently, not officially documented. This [S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18550606/5490505) kinda touches upon `$1`

Comment: [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) has some more info on the special regexp globals. "These global variables are thread-local and method-local variables."

Comment: **NB:** you must use single quotes (as in `'\1'`) **or** you must use a double backslash in double quotes (as in `"\\1"`).

Answer (score 31):

Keep in mind there's a third option, the block form of `sub`.  Sometimes you need it.  Say you want to replace some text with the reverse of that text.  You can't use $1 because it's not bound quickly enough:

```
"foobar".sub(/(.*)/, $1.reverse)  # WRONG: either uses a PREVIOUS value of $1, 
                                  # or gives an error if $1 is unbound
```

You also can't use `\1`, because the `sub` method just does a simple text-substitution of `\1` with the appropriate captured text, there's no magic taking place here:

```
"foobar".sub(/(.*)/, '\1'.reverse) # WRONG: returns '1\'
```

So if you want to do anything fancy, you should use the block form of `sub` ($1, $2, $`, $' etc. will be available):

```
"foobar".sub(/.*/){|m| m.reverse} # => returns 'raboof'
"foobar".sub(/(...)(...)/){$1.reverse + $2.reverse} # => returns 'oofrab'
```

Comment: Your example could be misleading - the match is what's passed to the block, not the matchgroups.  So, if you wanted to change "foobar" to "foorab", you'd have to do `str.sub(/(foo)(\w+)/) { $1 + $2.reverse }`

Comment: See ri String#sub:

     In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a 
     parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $' will be 
     set appropriately. The value returned by the block will be 
     substituted for the match on each call.