# Backslashes in gsub (escaping and backreferencing)

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, escaping, backreference

Consider the following snippet:

```
puts 'hello'.gsub(/.+/, '\0 \\0 \\\0 \\\\0')
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/9sHUR)):

```
hello hello \0 \0
```

This was very surprising, because I'd expect to see something like this instead:

```
hello \0 \hello \\0
```

My argument is that `\` is an escape character, so you write `\\` to get a literal backslash, thus `\\0` is a literal backslash `\` followed by `0`, etc. Obviously this is not how `gsub` is interpreting it, so can someone explain what's going on?

And what do I have to do to get the replacement I want above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escaping is limited when using single quotes rather then double quotes:

```
puts 'sinlge\nquote'
puts "double\nquote"
```

`"\0"` is the null-character (used i.e. in C to determine the end of a string), where as `'\0'` is `"\\0"`, therefore both `'hello'.gsub(/.+/, '\0')` and `'hello'.gsub(/.+/, "\\0")` return `"hello"`, but `'hello'.gsub(/.+/, "\0")` returns `"\000"`. Now `'hello'.gsub(/.+/, '\\0')` returning `'hello'` is ruby trying to deal with programmers not keeping the difference between single and double quotes in mind. In fact, this has nothing to do with `gsub`: `'\0' == "\\0"` and `'\\0' == "\\0"`. Following this logic, whatever you might think of it, this is how ruby sees the other strings: both `'\\\0'` and `'\\\\0'` equal `"\\\\0"`, which (when printed) gives you `\\0`. As gsub uses `\x` for inserting match number x, you need a way to escape `\x`, which is `\\x`, or in its string representation: `"\\\\x"`.

Therefore the line

```
puts 'hello'.gsub(/.+/, "\\0 \\\\0 \\\\\\0 \\\\\\\\0")
```

indeed results in

```
hello \0 \hello \\0
```

Comment: +1, yep. It has nothing to do with `gsub` at all. `puts '\0 \\0 \\\0 \\\\0'` prints `\0 \0 \\0 \\0` (http://ideone.com/3sPxD)