# Ruby: What does $1 mean?

Tags: ruby

I'm watching a RailsCast on polymorphic associations.   http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association?view=asciicast

There's three different models Article, Photo and Event that each take a comment from Comment.rb. (Article, Photo and Event each of a article_id, photo_id, and event_id). In listing the comments he has the problem of figuring out which of the 3 models to list the comments for, so he does this in the index action

```
def index
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comments = @commentable.comments
end


def find_commentable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

My question is, what is `$1`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to [Avdi Grimm from RubyTapas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288595/830639)

> $1 is a global variable which can be used in later code:
>
> ```
>  if "foobar" =~ /foo(.*)/ then 
>     puts "The matching word was #{$1}"
>  end
> ```
>
> **Output**:
>
> "The matching word was bar"

In short, $1, $2, $... are the global-variables used by some of the ruby library functions specially concerning `REGEX` to let programmers use the findings in later codes.

[See this](http://ruby.wikia.com/wiki/Special_variable) for such more variables available in Ruby.

Comment: its only created when using equal tilde operator??

Comment: Yes, `$1`, `$2` etc. match the first, second, etc. parenthesized groups in the last regular expression - see link in the answer. Rubocop recommends using `Regexp.last_match(n)` instead (note n is zero based, so `$1` == `#last_match(0)`

Answer (score 16):

The `$1` is group matched from the regular expression above `/(.+)_id$/`.  The `$1` variable is the string matched in the parenthesis.